# Create rows for missing values in SQL (data preparation for decision tree)

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, decision-tree

Currently, my table looks like this

```
id   | valName  | valCount | type
123  |   abb    |    3     |  2
123  |   abc    |    2     |  2
123  |    b     |    5     |  2
251  |   aaa    |    2     |  1
251  |   ab     |    2     |  1
251  |   abb    |    2     |  1
251  |   ac     |    2     |  1
```

and so on.
I want to fill in missing valNames for every id and set valCount to 0. If my set of distinct valName was (aaa, aab, ab, abb, abc, ac, b) it would look like this.

```
id   | valName  | valCount | type
123  |   aaa    |    0     |  2
123  |   aab    |    0     |  2
123  |   ab     |    0     |  2
123  |   abb    |    3     |  2
123  |   abc    |    2     |  2
123  |   ac     |    0     |  2
123  |    b     |    5     |  2
251  |   aaa    |    2     |  1
251  |   aab    |    0     |  1
251  |   ab     |    2     |  1
251  |   abb    |    2     |  1
251  |   abc    |    0     |  1
251  |   ac     |    2     |  1
251  |   b      |    0     |  1
```

Also, the dataset is quite large. So efficient query is better.

---

As Dale suggested, this is my attempt. **TABLE** in the code is the table I am using.

```
select  C.id, C.valName, C.type, COALESCE(D.valCount,0 ) as count

from (
    select *
    from (select id, min(type) as type
        From TABLE
        Group by id
    ) B
    cross join 
    (select distinct valName FROM TABLE) A
) C
left join TABLE D
on C.id = D.id
    and C.valName = D.valName
order by C.id
```

The idea behind this query is to create the id/valname table using cross join and then get valCount using left join.
This query works but is too slow.

Comment: The set of distinct valNames is a static list with persistent values (aaa, aab, ab, abb, abc, ac, b)?

Comment: If static list with persistent value means that the list never changes, it is. I want to have a separate row for each of the 7 valName for each id.

Comment: @Dale K added attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
with unq_id_type_cte(id, [type]) as (
    select distinct id, [type] from mytable)
insert mytable(id, valName, valCount, [type])
select uitc.id, t.v, 0, uitc.[type]
from
  (values ('aaa'),('aab'),('ab'),('abb'),('abc'),('ac'),('b')) t(v)
 cross join
  unq_id_type_cte uitc
where not exists
  (select 1 from mytable t_in where uitc.id=t_in.id
                                    and t.v=t_in.valName);
```

If there are performance issues or concerns then the first thing to try imo would be to insert the cte into an indexed temp table.